# How to add question mark parameter instead of forward slash in history js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I am trying to change the url like this (http://www.rangde.org/gift-cards?theme=Anniversary) 
But the output I am getting is (http://www.rangde.org/gift-cards/?theme=Anniversary) 
I dont want the forward slash in front of question mark parameter pls help me to fix this
My script is here:

```
 History.pushState({state:1,rand:Math.random()}, 'Designs', '?theme=Diwali');   
    function(){     
                var History = window.History, // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
                State = History.getState(),
                $log = $('#log');

                History.log('initial:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

                History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate

                var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
                History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
                }); 
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it a bug or a feature, but looks like adding an actual URL to the query helps:

```
History.pushState({}, 'New title', window.location.pathname + "?" + ...);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to trim the trailing '/' from the pathname.

Answer (score 0):

That is not achievable through Histor.js nor any other client side scripting... That should be done in server side.